# How to keep the DetailsView of a SfDataGrid expanded?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, syncfusion

I have a `SfDataGrid` and I made a `DetailsViewDefinition` for that. I also make `ExpandAllDetailsView` from code to expand all details and I want to keep these open, but right after the first reorder or first regroup these will collapse.

I tried kinda every events (what made sense) to reopen, but only the `MouseUp` was the closest to the goal, but that was kinda bad because it does not work on header and will reopen on every mouseups, so it was a very bad hack.

I would like to know a good and working way to **keep the rowdetail open even after events like reorder/group**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using SfDataGrid.ExpandAllDetailsView method. For grouping, you can achieve this by SfDataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions.CollectionChanged event,

```
this.dataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions.CollectionChanged += GroupColumnDescriptions_CollectionChanged;
private void GroupColumnDescriptions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
          new Action(() =>
          {
              this.dataGrid.ExpandAllDetailsView();
          }));
 }
```

For sorting you can achieve this by SfDataGrid.SortColumnsChanged event,

```
this.dataGrid.SortColumnsChanged += DataGrid_SortColumnsChanged;

private void DataGrid_SortColumnsChanged(object sender, GridSortColumnsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
         new Action(() =>
         {
             this.dataGrid.ExpandAllDetailsView();

         }));
}
```

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DetailsViewGrid_KeepExpand600241785)

Regards,

Susmitha S